# If you have multiple copies of a Component how do you trigger changes to them individually?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to use a computed property to trigger a bool within a component. I have multiple copies of this component but want to trigger them individually if each one meets the correct requirements. currently when the bool is set to true it effects all copies. Is there a standard way to handle this?

Comment: Are you defining `data` as a function?

Comment: This has been asked a number of times in different forms, although finding an exact duplicate to your question is difficult because it is so opinion-based and broad.  There are multiple techniques: props from a parent component holding state, events, shared services, and centralized state via Vuex.  The most appropriate methodology depends on your needs.

Comment: @EricGuan In the child component I have data as a function. I don't have my bool defined within data, it's tied directly to the computed function. 

<a v-bind:class="{ disabled: isDisabled }"></a>

isDisabled() {
//  if(this.id === "test1" ) {
  return true
  }
}

Comment: Try to add unique keys to your components (I assume you use v-for to generate a list of childs).

Comment: Please post some code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by creating a class object as a computed property. by default it flagged the class as disabled. I then used if statements to verify the name attached to each component, if true a flag would flip to true for that specific instance of the class. then finally a check to confirm that if the flag was set to true then activate the class. I'm sure there are more efficient ways, if you have one please share.

```
if(this.name === "Keywords" && this.view === "getViewCreateKeywords") {
        this.isActive = true;
    }

    if(this.name === "Listing" && this.view === "getViewCreateListing") {
        this.isActive = true;
    }

    if(this.name === "Backend" && this.view === "getViewCreateSummary") {
        this.isActive = true;
    }

    if(this.isActive) {
        return {
            disabled: this.isDisabled = false
        }
    }

    return {
        disabled: this.isDisabled = true
    }
```